# Difficulty finding elements in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to familiarize myself with Selenium and am running into an issue finding an element, I am noticing this a lot actually.

I want to go to yahoo.com, click on Sports, and assert the page title is correct.  The following throws an "Unable to locate element" error message.  I have tried ID, xPath etc.  I have also tried other page elements, Mail, News etc...all throw the same error. Am I missing something here?

```
import unittest
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# go to Yahoo home page, click on Sports and assert title is correct

class searchMaps(unittest.TestCase):
    # def setup as class method
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(inst):
        inst.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        inst.driver.maximize_window()
        inst.driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
        inst.driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    def test_click_sports_page(self):
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('yui_3_18_0_3_1527260025921_1028')
        self.search_field.click()
        actual_title = driver.getTitle()
        expected_title = 'Yahoo Sports | Sports News'
        assertEquals(actual_title, expected_title)


    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(inst):
        inst.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: isn't this id `yui_3_18_0_3_1527260025921_1028` dynamic and is supposed to change on next run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@id` of target link is dynamic, so it will be different each time you open the page.

Try to use link text to locate element:

```
self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sports')
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  That did get me past that error, but now I am seeing a NameError: name 'driver' is not defined in relation to the following: actual_title = driver.getTitle()

Comment: Try `actual_title = self.driver.title`

Comment: ah, thank you.  I am seeing other errors now but you solved my initial problem.  Ill work through the others.  Thanks for your help